# Backing up a table from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, file, backup

I'm trying to backup a table in my database to an .sql file.
I've found php code that is supposed to do this

```
$tablename = 'shooter';
$backupFile = 'backup\shooter.sql';
$query = $conn->query ("select * into outfile '$backupFile' from $tablename");
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

The $conn is connected to the database earlier in the code.
it seems to work except I can not file the shooter.sql file anywhere. I was thinking it would go into the backup directory on my computer.

Comment: The file is created on the MySQL server host, as mentioned in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: OK, is there a way to put that file onto my local computer.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. There are other programs like [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) you can use to create a backup.

Comment: I'm really new at PHP and I was reading about the mysqldump and I'm more confused now would you be able to give me an example of the mysqldump code.

Comment: It's not a "code", it's a separate program.

Comment: I do another approach running a cronjob every night. With that I have a backup for every day and the oldest one is kept 7 days. It also will be uploaded to a s3 storage  https://pastebin.com/t3RhYVce

Comment: *I've found php code that is supposed to do this* No. This code exports the table data only to TSV file (tabular-separated values). Its output is common text file, not .SQL script, and it does not contain table's structure.

Comment: I've found another way that will work for me.  I've created a backup table in my database and have the sql insert table1 select * from table2 this works just great.  Thanks for all your input.